# My custom theme does not apply to buttons

Tags: android, android-theme

i have been created a custom theme with following XML representation:

```
<style name="ABTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
      <item name="android:textColor" >#ffbb22</ item>
      <item name="android:background" >#ff1a557c</ item>
      <item name="android:button" >@style/ABButton</ item>
</style >
```

And i implemented **ABButton** in another XML file:

```
<style name="ABButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:padding" >3dp</ item>
    <item name="android:background" >#121212</ item>
    <item name="android:textColor" >#ffffff</ item>
</style >
```

But the button styles does not apply to buttons, and buttons will have the default Android style, Can someone tell me how i can fix this problem
thanks

Note that i applied `ABTheme` to my main activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your parent Style

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ABButton</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
**themes.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="ABTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="myButton">@style/ABButton</item>
    </style >
</resources>
**styles.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="ABButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#121212</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style >
</resources>
**attrs.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="myButton" format="reference" />
</resources>

**xml**
<Button
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="My Custom Button"
 style="?myButton"/>

**AndroidManifest.xml**
<application
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:theme="@style/ABTheme"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
     // define your activity here
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:theme="@style/mytheme"` inside the manifest on your activity. for example

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.riverwalklabs.eggzammobile.YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/mytheme" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: the theme has been applied to activity but not to buttons

Comment: try using normal button like this `  <Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Button" />
`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the root theme changed with Honeycomb. What used to be "android:style/Theme" is now "android:Theme.Holo". Likewise, what used to be "android:Widget.Button" is now "android:Widget.Holo.Button".

Another problem I see is that you're using "android:button" instead of "android:buttonStyle".

You'll have to create a style for API 11+ and another for older devices (unless you don't plan on supporting anything older than Honeycomb). Then you'll have to put them in separate resource folders.

It'll be something like this:

**res/values/style.xml:**

```
<style name="ABTheme" parent="android:Theme">
      <item name="android:textColor" >#ffbb22</ item>
      <item name="android:background" >#ff1a557c</ item>
      <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ABButton</item>
</style >
<style name="ABButton" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:padding" >3dp</ item>
    <item name="android:background" >#121212</ item>
    <item name="android:textColor" >#ffffff</ item>
</style >
```

**res/values-v11/style.xml:**

```
<style name="ABTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
      <item name="android:textColor" >#ffbb22</ item>
      <item name="android:background" >#ff1a557c</ item>
      <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ABButton</item>
</style >
<style name="ABButton" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
    <item name="android:padding" >3dp</ item>
    <item name="android:background" >#121212</ item>
    <item name="android:textColor" >#ffffff</ item>
</style >
```

Comment: Thanks but eclipse give me an **error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.**

Comment: You'll have to build against API 11 or higher to get the Holo theme.